# Where does MobaXterm keep its home directory?

Tags: mobaxterm

I have found MobaXterm to be a very useful terminal client, but I really want to be able to move files into and out of the home directory `/home/mobaxterm`. On my Windows filesystem, that is not a valid path, so where is `/home/mobaxterm` really located on my Windows filesystem?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can see where the home directory is stored (and open it in Windows explorer) by using the following command:

```
open /home/mobaxterm
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer solved my problem. Later I noticed that there was an option for setting a `Persistent home directory` as noted in my answer below. If you didn't know about it, I thought you might be interested.

Comment: Also: `open "$HOME"`

Comment: For mine the above will open the wrong directory for some reason, for those who are like me, and if you didn't modified the config. The location of home will be here: `C:\Users\{USERNAME}\DOCUME~1\MOBAXT~1\home`

Answer (score 16):

Go to `Settings`->`Configuration`->`General` and set the `Persistent home directory` to the folder of your choice. Then you will obviously know where it is.

However, if you have not done this before and you already have files in that directory and want to copy them out, try looking in 
`C:\Users\your_username_here\AppData\Local\Temp\Mxt73\tmp\home_your_username_here`. (assuming version 7.3, you might want to try Mxt7**N** for other versions like 7.**N**). After you've copied your files, then set a persistent directory so that next time it will be easier to find.

Answer (score 13):

You can always use

```
open `pwd`
```

to open current working directory in Windows Explorer !

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is probably:

`open ~`