# MobaXterm Local Terminal Doesn't work - Closes immediately

Tags: terminal, mobaxterm

I'm able to SSH to into other machines using MobaXterm, but  when I try to run the Local terminal, the Tab just opens and closes all by its own. Am I missing something like a config file ? I tried running it as an Admin as well, but no luck.

I am on Windows 7 Enterprise Edition 64bit and started with MobaXterm v9.0. I tried totally uninstalling MobaXterm v9.0 (including deleting the CygUtils plugin) and then installing the latest MobaXterm v9.1 and CygUtils plugin. However, the same problem persists.

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise Edition 64bit and MobaXterm v9.0  @ChristopherBottoms

Comment: I tried upgrading, but that didnt help @ChristopherBottoms

Comment: Tried it... Doesnt work ! :(

Comment: haha... Yeah... that's the first thing I did

Comment: Aditya, were you able to fix this? I started having the same issue!

Comment: @Mohy Eldeen...  Unfortunately no

Comment: Okay. I had the same issue in installed verion. Fixed by Resetting the configuration. Settings->Reset configuration -> Reset the entire MobaXterm configuration

Answer (score 4):

Same problem form me, solved by backup and then delete the config file:

`C:\Users\Your_Name\Documents\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.ini`

if you have changed you document home directory, then find the file `MobaXterm.ini` in MobaXterm of that directory.

You can use the tools `everything` to find it easily.

Comment: This worked for me on windows 10.

Comment: It worked also for me but the file is placed in the following folder:  ```C:\Users\Your_Name\AppData\Roaming\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.ini ```

Answer (score 3):

Update: I just now helped someone with this and the solution that worked was uninstalling the "installation" version and then downloading and using the "portable" version.

For my installation, there are files in `C:\Users\username\Documents\MobaXterm`.

Perhaps back them up (especially if you have SSH keys or other important files or configuration in them) and then delete that directory before another clean install of MobaXterm.

If you've tried all of the solutions on this page that make sense, you can also try [contacting Mobatek](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/contact.html) to file a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in the portable version. I fixed the problem in 3 steps :

1. I downloaded the **CygUtils.plugin** (http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/CygUtils.plugin),
2. Put the file above in the directory where MobaXterm exe file is
3. I removed **MobaXterm .log**, **.ini** and **backup files** in the same directory

Comment: REALLY ?!? you honestly instruct us to remove .ini and *LOSE ALL SAVED SESSIONS* ?!? thank you very much, FOR NOTHING !!!!

Answer (score 2):

You must enable **Enable Windows Subsystem for Linux** feature on Windows 10 and then it works. Here is a link how you can enable this:
[How to Enable Windows Subsystem for Linux](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/enable-bash-windows-10-anniversary-update)

Comment: please note that I specifically mentioned that this error occurs on a Windows 7 machine, NOT A WINDOWS 10 machine.

Comment: Please note, that this actually fixed my problem.  Thanks Stefan.

Comment: TURN THE POWER ON DUDE ... not only that I have the same problem, and WSL is on, but cygwin HAS *NOTHING* TO DO with WSL, and MobaXTerm is based on cygwin, otherwise it will NOT work on older windows

Comment: Note that I have the same issue as the OP but I am under WSL (v1) and Windows 10. It lacks documentation on how to configure the automatically created WSL session. It returns immediately when I connect to WSL.

Answer (score 2):

Like others I openen C:\Users\username\Documents\MobaXterm, but deletion of the MobaXterm.ini did not help. I also had to delete the .log file before MobaXterm woke up again.

Tip: do not delete the .ini file but rename it to MobaXterm.bak.ini. This way you still can copy some of the old configuration data out of it to use in the new one. I saved my bookmarks this way.

Answer (score 0):

You must download **CygUtils.plugin** and put it in same directory MobaXterm exe file is. This apply to install & portable version.

This plugin is required to run local terminal. You can find this information on 'Home screen' on the bottom. There is also direct link to download it.

You can get it from here: http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/CygUtils.plugin

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having `CygUtils.plugin` in the same directory as `MobaXterm.exe` (or `MobaXterm_Personal_10.5.exe` in my case), you may need to **set your MobaXterm home directory** (and possibly root directory) to Windows folders to which you have modify access. You can do this in MobaXterm by going to Settings->Configuration->General and setting the "Persistent home directory" and "Persistent root (/) directory" to the folders of your choice. Worked for me. I was inspired to try this by stumbling on  [Where does MobaXterm keep its home directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/902765/where-does-mobaxterm-keep-its-home-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. The problem was due to a dll conflict between cygwin and mobaxterm (which is delivered with an integrated cygwin). I removed the path of original cygwin from the %PATH% environment variable, rebooted the PC, and everything works fine now.

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to remove everything from the installed directory, except the .ini file and licence file. Then put the portable version in the same directory.